# Plotly Express not importing after installation in Juypiter

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to import plotly.express but I get the follow error:

`AttributeError: module plotly.colors has no attribute named_colorscales`

Code to import:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
fig=go.Figure()
```

I have installed plotly express this morning using:

`conda install -c plotly plotly_express`

It appears to have been successfully installed without errors, but when I import it, the above error appears.

Kernel was restarted post installation.

EDIT:  I have amended the code slightly as there was a slight error and an redundant import.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of work, it looks like the version of Plotly that I was using was out of date.  I have upgraded that and it appears to have worked. Out of desperation, I decided to try upgrade plotly.express and it was out of date. After upgrade, worked like a charm.

Comment: You should add some more details to your answer, then accept your own answer. This ensures people with the same problem can be directed to the right place. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah definitely! I think once two days have passed from the time you asked, you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/#:~:text=You%20must%20wait%202%20days,and%20earn%20the%20accepted%20answer.) since it worked for you. Hopefully it will work for anyone else who has the same issue